# Image on rss feed on post

Tags: posts, images, rss

I want my website to display post of bloggers fashion posts from a virtual world second life.

I've started using blogger, they have a simple widget "bloglist", just put the url of the blogger it also show pictures of recent post per url. Someone told me to move to wordpress because it's better layout. I'm using Wordpress now, but I'm totally lost.

What type of plugins, codes or widgets do I need to get this same result in Wordpress? I know rss feed, but it does not show an image with the post feed. What do I need to achieve this?

Here are examples of what I'm trying to achieve

> behappyinsl.wordpress.com/
>
> www.old-london-docks.de/
>   fashionfeedofsl.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a plugin. A couple of options are

- [RSS Image Feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-image-feed/)
- [WP RSS Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-images/)